# Stripe do not save card detail in test server only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, stripe-payments

The card is being add in development server. But--while running test server and adding card detail for cucumber test--it doesn't save the card and shows the following error.

```
ERROR Stripe::InvalidRequestError: Invalid token id: tok_18879VHs1bT44hDtvyLbWjOk
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Invalid token id" error happens when you are not using the correct API key in your code. What this means is that you created the token `tok_18879VHs1bT44hDtvyLbWjOk` with the publishable API key from one Stripe account and then tried to charge that token server-side with the Secret API key from a different Stripe account.

Double-check your code and make sure that you use the correct API keys both for the Publishable and for the Secret key. You can find yours here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys